# Python counting ngram frequency in large files

Tags: python, string, count, frequency, n-gram

I have a file that is 699Mb containing N-Grams, I have tried the following code to count the frequency of each N-Gram however when i run it i get a memory error or the program crashes.

```
from collections import Counter
import sys

c = Counter()
with open('Output.txt') as myfile:
    for line in myfile:
        c.update(line.split())

print(c)

with open('NGramCountOutput.txt', 'w') as outgrams:
    outgrams.write(str(c))
```

Can anyone suggest a more elegant solution to solve this problem or suggest another approach.

Answer (score 3):

Try iterating over `c` instead of stringifying it in-memory:

```
for k in c:
    outgrams.write("{0}: {1}".format(k, c[k]))
```

Comment: or even - ```for k,v in c.items(): outgrams.write("{}: {}".format(k, v))```

Comment: Given that the ngrams are uniquified before any stringification, unless _most_ ngrams are unique, the memory cost of the `str` won't be that high (and it will pale in comparison to the cost of the `Counter` itself in all cases). This is a possible problem/solution, but not the most likely one (it would only occur if you were already treading very close to the system memory limits, and unique ngrams were very common).

Comment: @wwii: Or while we're going for ridiculous optimization, the version from my answer, `from itertools import starmap`, `outgrams.writelines(starmap('{}: {}\n'.format, c.items()))`, which pushes all the work to the C layer to run faster (I added a new line, because lacking one would make counts run into following ngrams).

Comment: @ShadowRanger - i wasn't going for any optimization, I just like that form better, it is easier for me to read.

Comment: @wwii: True, yours was mostly just correct, rather than primarily optimizing. Avoiding unnecessary lookups _is_ more performant, but it's really the properly naming key and value (in a real use, you wouldn't use `k`/`v` usually) that makes it better by making the code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

Psychic debugging: Your input file is actually a single line, containing all the ngrams. So when you do:

```
for line in myfile:
    c.update(line.split())
```

it's actually reading in the whole file as a single "line", then splitting it into a `list` of all the ngrams. Problem is, that means a *huge* memory cost to store individual copies of all the ngrams momentarily before they get dedup-ed in `Counter` (a three letter ASCII `str` in Python 3.5 x64 uses ~52 bytes, plus another 8 bytes for the reference to it in the resulting `list`; if you read in a line that's 699 MB of three letter strings with a space between each of them, then split it, you'll produce ~183 million of these strings, which means a rough lower bound on memory usage would be 183000000 * 60, or around 10 GB of memory. The costs would be lower on 32 bit machines, but not more than 50% (and likely less); on a 32 bit machine, you don't have enough virtual memory address space to store 5 GB (most 32 bit machines are limited to 2 GB).

The easiest fix would be to split your file up to put each ngram on its own line (or limit the number of ngrams per line to a reasonable number). For example, with `tr` (on UNIX-like machines), the conversion is trivial:

```
tr ' ' '\n' < Output.txt > OutputNewlines.txt
```

Similar approaches can be used in many text editors with find/replace.

If that's not an option, you'll want to explicitly read block by block, rather than line-by-line, processing all stuff before the last space, saving what remains, then reading another block.

```
from functools import partial

c = Counter()
with open('Output.txt') as myfile:
    remainder = ''
    # Read file by fixed size blocks, not lines, assuming no ngram is larger than 8192
    for block in iter(partial(myfile.read, 8192), ''):
        # Split off the last whitespace separated piece (might span to next block)
        parts = (remainder + block).rsplit(None, 1)
        # Handle block with and without whitespace identically; no whitespace means
        # probably handling EOF, just process what we've got and set remainder empty
        toprocess, remainder = (parts + [''])[:2]
        c.update(toprocess.split())
    c.update(remainder.split())  # Add whatever was left over
```

That should limit maximum memory usage to be proportionate to the number of unique ngrams, not the number of total, non-unique ngrams on a line.

If you have relatively few unique ngrams, then that's enough. If you have a lot of unique ngrams though, stringifying the `Counter` could cost a lot of memory too (though the `Counter` itself would be using far more, the `str` would just be the straw that broke the camel's back). A simple way to print the counts one per line is:

```
from itertools import starmap

with open('NGramCountOutput.txt', 'w') as outgrams:
    # On Python 2, use .iteritems() instead of .items() to avoid large temp list
    # If a temp list is okay, and you want sorted output by count,
    # use .most_common() over .items()
    outgrams.writelines(starmap('{} {}\n'.format, c.items()))
```